# Close application after closing dialog window

Tags: c#, wpf, dialog, startup

Sorry for (maybe) easy question, but how can I shut down application, when I close dialog window ( which I called before running MainWindow) ?

As I mentioned above, before running MainWindow in my application I call a Dialog window. In App.xml I added this:

```
Startup="Application_Startup"
```

Then in App.xml.cs I wrote this:

```
    public partial class App : Application
{
    private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        Current.ShutdownMode = ShutdownMode.OnExplicitShutdown;
        StartWindow startWindow = new StartWindow();
        startWindow.ShowDialog();
    }

}
```

In my StartWindow there are only two exits - *connect* button, that worked fine, and classic closing button on title bar. I would like this button to shut down my application.

In my class StartWindow I wrote this:

```
        private void Window_Closed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        DialogResult = false;
    }
```

But it still runs my MainWindow after closing my StartWindow. I even tried

```
        private void Window_Closed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult = false;
        Application.Current.Shutdown();
    }
```

But still. Even if in above code I changed rows.

What I am doing wrong? I suspect, that is very easy to program what I want, but I don't know how. Yet. Can you help me, please?

Answer (score 0):

`ShowDialog()` has a return value.

```
bool? dialogResult = startWindow.ShowDialog();
if (dialogResult == false)
{
    ...
}
```

You have to set `DialogResult` in your `StartWindow` before closing it, but you have already done that.